# substr_count within array

Tags: php, arrays, count, substr

I am trying to search for a keyword within strong tags.

I have produced an array for the tags which displays as:

```
        Array
        (
        [0] => Array
        (
        [0] =>  seo agency in london
        [1] => seo agency in london
        [2] => seo consultant in london
        [3] => seo consultant in london
        [4] => seo experts in london
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
        [0] =>  seo agency in london
        [1] => seo agency in london
        [2] => seo consultant in london
        [3] => seo consultant in london
        [4] => seo experts in london
        )

        )
```

And I want to search for the keyword which in this case is "seo"

I am using:

```
function substr_count_array( $haystack, $needle ) {
$count = 0;
foreach ($needle as $substring) {
$count += substr_count( $haystack, $substring);
}
return $count;
}
$matchPattern7 = '/<strong(?:"(?:[^\\\"]|\\\.)*"|\'(?:[^\\\\\']|\\\.)*\'|[^\'">])*>(.*?)<\/strong>/';
preg_match_all($matchPattern7, $content, $foundIt7);
echo substr_count_array(strtolower($foundIt7), strtolower($keyword));
```

For reference..

$keyword = seo

I am getting zero, can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of some regex which will break.

Comment: @PeeHaa Who said he didn't use DomDocument to get the content of the `<strong>` tags? I'm all for using DomDocument for parsing HTML, but this question can not be solved by DomDocument alone.

Comment: @BerryLangerak It's just a suggestion, otherwise it would have been in the answer section :)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for stopping by. I am using simple html dom to produce the results.

Comment: You're foreach loop won't even execute once since you are looping through your needle as though it were an array. Your needle is the string "seo". Also the $haystack parameter sent to your function is not actually a haystack, it is an array of haystacks. Better to call it $haystackAr not to get confused. Then loop through $haystackAr not $needle. I posted an answer with tested code to see this in a working example.

Comment: @BerryLangerak Because of the fact I see this thing in OPs question perhaps??? `$matchPattern7 = '/<strong(?:"(?:[^\\\"]|\\\.)*"|\'(?:[^\\\\\']|\\\.)*\'|[^\'">])*>(.*?)<\/strong>/';`. And P.S. I never said this solves OP question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and works for me:

```
$foundIt7=array();
$foundIt7[1]=array(0 => ' seo agency in london',
        1 => 'seo agency in london',
        2 => 'seo consultant in london',
        3 => 'seo consultant in london',
        4 => 'seo experts in london');
print_r($foundIt7[1]);


function substr_count_array( $haystackAr, $needle ) {
$count = 0;
foreach ($haystackAr as $haystack) {
$count += substr_count( $haystack, $needle);
}
return $count;
}

echo substr_count_array($foundIt7[1],'seo');//returns 5
```

Comment: Hi Ultimater, Thanks for your input. How can I do it where I do not have to specify the array names. Ie.. preg_match_all($matchPattern7, $content, $foundIt7) is producing the array and it will be different each time so I wont know what is produced on the array but need to search for a set keyword on it. If could email me that would be great?

Comment: My code does that already, just comment out the print_r and use preg_match_all($matchPattern7, $content, $foundIt7) to populate your $foundIt7 array. Then simply execute `echo substr_count_array($foundIt7, strtolower($keyword));` to count your matches. If you want to apply strtolower to the array, you will need to do that from within the loop.

Comment: That works great, thanks! If you'd like to help out with a few other bits as freelance job please email me james(dot)deadman(at)gmail(dot)com

Answer (score 0):

```
function substr_count_array( $haystack, $needle ) {
$count = 0;
foreach ( $haystack as $substring) {
foreach($substring as $string)
{
$count += substr_count($string, $haystack);
}
}
return $count;
}
```

Comment: sorry u need to use  $haystack in 1st loop

Comment: still 0 I'm afraid. Thank you very much for your input though